# Form not updating info in database

Tags: php, sql-server, forms, pdo, sql-update

I have the following code which is supposed to update info in database in certain conditions:

if password is set, do update 1, else do update 2.

Submit button seems to work, i tried to echo data after submit and all it's ok. I put an echo test for first update and seems to print the test (but it's not updating in sql server). I tried the same in the second update, and nothing printed.

What am i doing wrong ? Thank you.

```
function check_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}



//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

$id = check_input($_POST['id']);
$username = check_input($_POST['username']);
$password = check_input($_POST['password']);
$passwordConfirm = check_input($_POST['passwordConfirm']);
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$activity = isset($_POST['activity']) ? 1 : 0;


    //basic validation
    if($username ==''){
        $error[] = 'Trebuie introdus un nume.';
    }

    if( strlen($password) > 0){

        if($password ==''){
            $error[] = 'Trebuie introdusa o parola.';
        }

        if($passwordConfirm ==''){
            $error[] = 'Trebuie introdusa o parola de confirmare.';
        }

        if($password != $passwordConfirm){
            $error[] = 'Parolele nu se potrivesc.';
        }

    }


    if($email ==''){
        $error[] = 'Trebuie introdusa o adresa de email.';
    }

    if(!isset($error)){

        try {

            if(isset($password)){

                $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                //update database
                $stmt = $handler->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :username, password = :password, email = :email, activity = :activity WHERE id = :id') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':id' => $id,
                    ':activity' => $activity
                ));

            } else {

                //update database
                $stmt = $handler->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :username, email = :email, activity = :activity WHERE id = :id') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':id' => $id,
                    ':activity' => $activity
                ));



            }


            //redirect to index page
            //header('Location: userlist.php?action=updated');
            //exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>




<?php
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo $error.'<br />';
    }
}

    try {

        $stmt2 = $handler->prepare('SELECT id, name, email, activity FROM users WHERE id = :id') ;
        $stmt2->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
        $row = $stmt2->fetch(); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>







<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
<fieldset>

<legend><span style="margin-left:50px">Actualizare informatii utilizator</span></legend>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Nume utilizator</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="username" value='<?php echo $row['name']; ?>' class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Parola</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="password"  class="form-control input-md" type="password">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Confirma parola</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="passwordConfirm"  class="form-control input-md" type="password">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Adresa email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" class="form-control input-md" type="email">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">Activitate utilizator</label>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">
      <input name="activity"  <?php  if ($row['activity'] == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"';}  ?>  type="checkbox">
    </label> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="send"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Trimite" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</div>


</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: did you getting any error ?

Comment: From where you are getting `id` in `$id = check_input($_POST['id']);`??

Comment: @JYoThl there was no error

Comment: @Nana Partykar Ohhh, you're a savior !!! That was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @IonutP. You should get the id from the session (assuming the user id logged in) and not form, because someone could change the id. This make taking ownership of an account so easy, you just have to know the id...